# JSONB filter on select via Supabase

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, supabase

I have such a logic (**attributes column's type is JSONB** - array of objects) that works:

[image]

But I want to implement logical OR here if trait_type is equal ... not AND:

[image]

JSONB's column structure:

```
[
   {
      "value":"Standard Issue Armor 1 (Purple)",
      "trait_type":"Clothes"
   },
   {
      "value":"Standard Issue Helmet 1 (Red)",
      "trait_type":"Full Helmet"
   },
   {
      "value":"Chrome",
      "trait_type":"SmartSkin"
   },
   {
      "value":"Base Drone (Blue)",
      "trait_type":"Drone"
   },
   {
      "value":"Thick",
      "trait_type":"Eyebrows"
   }
]
```

How that could be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could paste your original code as text and not as image, it would be super helpful for anyone trying to write up an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't verify the code, so might not work, but I believe at least is in the right direction. You can use the [`.or()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/next/or) filter to connect multiple filters with logical or operator. For `contains()`, you can use the `cs` keyword inside the or filter like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('NTFs')
  .select('name, id_in_collection, owner_address')
  .eq('collection_id', Number(id))
  .contains('attributes', JSON.stringify([{trait_type: 'SmartSkin', value: 'Chrome'}]))
  .or(`attributes.cs.${JSON.stringify([{trait_type: 'Drone', value: 'Armed Drone (Blue)'}])}`, `attributes.cs.${JSON.stringify([{trait_type: 'Drone', value: 'Armed Drone (Green)'}])}`)
  .order('id_in_collection')
  .range(fromIndex, toIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found why it was not working.
My Jsonb was define as an **array**, ***avoid it.***

Secondly i would like to filter values by different operator so i created a function

This function is now dynamic, and i can call it in my code with supabase RPC

This is my function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_maintenances(
  search_column text,
  search_operator text,
  search_value text
) RETURNS SETOF maintenances AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
    'SELECT m.*
     FROM maintenances m
     CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(m.values) as fields
     WHERE fields->>%L %s %L',
     search_column, search_operator, search_value
  );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Replace "maintenances" by your table name and m."values" by your column name and name it as you wish.

now you can execute it in your code

```
const fetchMaintenances = async () => {
    const {data, error} = await supabase.rpc("get_maintenances", {
      search_column: "value",
      search_operator: "ilike",
      search_value: "f%"
    })
    return data
  }
```

Enjoy !